# how to update by query limit document by from and size in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

i have used _update_by_query with elasticsearch and i want to use from and size to limited num of documents for business of customers and i have a problem

> Validation Failed: 1: from is not supported in this context;

In elasticsearch is there any way to update_by_query with limited parameters?

Comment: Like the error says `from` cannot be applied so you need to find a way to filter results based on some condition. May be filter query / painless script. Cant say without knowing problem statement.

Comment: hi @TheUknown query i used below :
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "employees_id": -1
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "search_level_id": "16"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.employees_id=2",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}

Comment: Elastic will not allow you to update only first. You should remove `from`. It will then update all records where `employees_id = -1 AND search_level_id = 16`. Unless if you want to do only 10 you might need a work around. May be reindex first 10 records into another index. Update by query on  new index and then reindex back to original index

Comment: many thanks @TheUknown

Comment: In Elasticsearch 7 there seems to be a new URL parameter for this: [max_docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/docs-update-by-query.html)